# Whether allowing only Alphanumeric User Input in an PHP application can prevent XSS attack?

Tags: javascript, php, security

I developed a PHP application where I allowed only alphanumeric characters as User input. Whether it can prevent XSS attack. I used JavaScript for user input fields which does not allow other characters than alphabets and numbers.

Comment: JS is easily bypassed, you need that kind of sanitization in the BACKEND

Comment: _“where I allow3ed only alphanumeric characters as User input”_ – if there is no solid reason to restrict user input like that, but your only argument _for_ it is that it might be “more secure” in any regard – then you’re approaching it the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0):

XSS prevention behavior changes depends on context.

**HTML Context**
Encoding only < and >  will be enough for HTML context.

**Attribute Context**
Always use double quote for attribute defination.

Encoding double quotes will be enough for attribute context.

**Javascript Context**
This is slightly hard to handle all cases. But you need to use double quato for variables  defination.

var foo = "USER_INPUT"

Encoding double quatos, < and >  will be enough javascript context.